# How to make page cannot scrolled down with button toggle?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a JavaScript code that could make a HTML page not scrollable unless a user clicks a button. For example, I have a floating button and when the user clicks that button, the page can be scrolled normally and the button gets hidden, otherwise the page keep stays freeze (non-scrollable).

I have little knowledge of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that effect by adding a CSS class containing `overflow: none:` rule.

In the example below I have a button which toggles `noScroll` CSS class on body element. You can apply that class to any element that you want to prevent from scrolling.

```js
function toggleScroll() {
  const element = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
  element.classList.toggle('noScroll');
}
```

```css
.noScroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}


.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleScroll()">Toggle scroll</button>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

To toggle (add and remove) noScroll CSS class, I used classList property, you can see docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/classList